# Bike advice quick release thru axle lever videos included

Tags: repair, advice

my thru axle was installed for the last time before breaking here

the installation thru axle before it broke

then after me explaining in the video and the issue as it stands now.

the issue

im looking for a solution to get this axle out, plan to go to shop monday.

the issue written which can be seen and heard in above videos.

Installed the thru axle i always do, attempted to take it out at a stand. the axle level came off, screwed it back on it just came off again.

im looking for a solution on how to remove  the axle out if anyone knows how.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It would really help the searchability of your question if you included a short list of the important points for each video.

Comment: As it looks look you installed the axle in complete darkness are you sure you installed the right axle ? I ask because I know certain frames don’t always comply with the standard. My Cube GTC carbon has a weird 6.34mm thread so I can’t use any standard axle, plus for what reason did you attempt this in pitch black darkness ? Why was it imperative it was done at that point and couldn’t wait till daylight?

Answer (score 1):

It does not look good.

You may be better letting a shop give it a shot vs. risking damaging anything else. I am sure a good shop has seen this more than any of us here and will be able to try to get it out without damaging anything else along the way.

In the forums I saw it seemed like some drastic things had to happen like cutting hubs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the style of thru-axle you have in there right now. Most are effectively just plain old bolts with an internal hex fitting on either end. The DT Swiss RWS axle you have as the new one is a proven alternative. It does look to be some kind of expansion plug-type thing though, so try giving the lever a good whack with a hammer. Perhaps the wedge that expands the end of the axle got stuck or is corroded in place.

Other options include:

- Use either slip joint pliers, vice grip pliers, or a pipe wrench to grab the exposed part of the axle on the non-drive side and remove it.
- Use a rotary tool to cut wrench flats on the axle so you can put a wrench on it to unscrew it.